# Convert Formated Date Text to Date value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can i convert this text "Sunday, 24 March 2013, 11:42 pm" to "24/03/2013 11:42 AM" date value in excel?

Comment: If the answer by vatsal is not sufficient, you will need to give more information about your problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that text in A2 try this formula in B2

`=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,99),",","")+0`

Custom format B2 with the required format, i.e. **dd/mm/yyyy h:mm AM/PM**